# Docker Error : no space left on device on windows

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm using docker on windows 7 and trying to download an image from cloud. After downloading while extraction i'm getting an error. Below is log snippet

```
cba922442da5: Downloading 5.866 GB/5.866 GB
10d186ab9b98: Download complete
89c26a498cda: Download complete
write /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob601918967: no space left on devic
e

 Tools docker image has been downloaded or upgraded to the newer version success
fully if already exist
```

There are already several thread related to this issue & i have tried solution provided by them but they didn't work. i have tried to delete all the images using below command but got certificate error

```
$ docker ps -a -q
time="2017-03-30T13:09:16+05:30" level=info msg="Unable to use system certificat
e pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
```

Docker config file

```
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "192.234.345.231",
        "MachineName": "default",
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 53944,
        "SSHKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,
        "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3326",
        "SwarmDiscovery": "",
        "VBoxManager": {},
        "HostInterfaces": {},
        "CPU": 1,
        "Memory": 1024,
        "DiskSize": 60000,
        "NatNicType": "82540EM",
        "Boot2DockerURL": "",
        "Boot2DockerImportVM": "",
        "HostDNSResolver": false,
        "HostOnlyCIDR": "192.134.77.1/24",
        "HostOnlyNicType": "82540EM",
        "HostOnlyPromiscMode": "deny",
        "UIType": "headless",
        "HostOnlyNoDHCP": false,
        "NoShare": false,
        "DNSProxy": true,
        "NoVTXCheck": false,
        "ShareFolder": ""
    },
    "DriverName": "virtualbox",
    "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "Disk": 0,
        "EngineOptions": {
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Dns": null,
            "GraphDir": "",
            "Env": [],
            "Ipv6": false,
            "InsecureRegistry": [],
            "Labels": [],
            "LogLevel": "",
            "StorageDriver": "",
            "SelinuxEnabled": false,
            "TlsVerify": true,
            "RegistryMirror": [],
            "InstallURL": "https://get.docker.com"
        },
        "SwarmOptions": {
            "IsSwarm": false,
            "Address": "",
            "Discovery": "",
            "Agent": false,
            "Master": false,
            "Host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3326",
            "Image": "swarm:latest",
            "Strategy": "spread",
            "Heartbeat": 0,
            "Overcommit": 0,
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "ArbitraryJoinFlags": [],
            "Env": null,
            "IsExperimental": false
        },
        "AuthOptions": {
            "CertDir": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\certs",
            "CaCertPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\ca.pem",
            "CaPrivateKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\ca-key.pem",
            "CaCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerCertPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\server.pem",
            "ServerKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\server-key.pem",
            "ClientKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\key.pem",
            "ServerCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
            "ClientCertPath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\cert.pem",
            "ServerCertSANs": [],
            "StorePath": "C:\\Users\\sbha5\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default"
        }
    },
    "Name": "default"
}
```

Docker info

```
$ docker info
time="2017-03-30T13:13:35+05:30" level=info msg="Unable to use system certificat
e pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.57-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 17.03.1-ce (TCL 7.2); HEAD : 4c264fa - Tue Mar 28
21:11:51 UTC 2017
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.8 MiB
Name: default
ID: WVD7:APIY:7JVZ:HEY7:TJKR:UH3U:PQLR:PTSK:OIOY:ERF3:UIPR:FRE3
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 15
 Goroutines: 23
 System Time: 2017-03-30T07:43:35.782810077Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Username: cartdocker
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

If it's memory or storage issue please let me know how to increase memory. I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 15):

Start by doing some cleaning of the unused/stopped images and containers.

```
$ docker ps -a
$ docker images -a
$ docker container prune
$ docker image prune
```

You may also log in to boot2docker and inspect filesystem usage:

```
> boot2docker ssh
$ df -kh
```

Additionally you may consider increasing boot2docker's volume size, although I didn't find it in live documentation (just [this md](https://github.com/fabric8io/jenkinshift/blob/master/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/docs/articles/b2d_volume_resize.md)).